# replace variables onclick react

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, onclick, state

I am fairly new to react, and dont know much about states and stuff... I have an accordion with different accordion items. I also have a list of text i want to use in this i want to map trough.
The code looks like this:

Accordion:

```
const Accordion = () => (
  <ul className="hw-accordion hw-block--mt hw-block--mb" data-hw-accordion>
    {questions.map((value, index) => {
      return <Accordion_item title={value.question} desc={value.answer}/>
    })}
  </ul>
);
```

The questions is supposed to change whenever a user clicks a button, but thats not happening in my case.

questions:

```
import en from './questions_en'
import no from './questions_no'
import sv from './questions_sv'
import da from './questions_da'
import { getLocale } from "../../util/locale";

const questions = () => {
  switch(getLocale()) {

    case "no":   return no;
    case "en":   return en;
    case "da":   return da;
    case "sv":   return sv;

    default:      return no
  }
};


export default questions();
```

This works fine as a static variable, but does not work on the button onclick. Aka. This is the class i really have to change. 
I know that i have to change the state somehow... so i have tried to build a class with functions, but i have failed every time now.

Can someone give me an example of how i can create a function that changes the "questions" variable onclick?

Comment: Where is the button inside accordion or outside?

Comment: the button is outside the accordion :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have `useState` (if you use functional component) or `this.state` (if you use class component). Here I assume you use functional component so useState will be something like

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
```

and on button click you should be set questions using setQuestions like below:

```
<button onClick={()=>{ setQuestions(`Your new questions should be set here`);}}>Change Question</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import en from './questions_en'
import no from './questions_no'
import sv from './questions_sv'
import da from './questions_da'

const QuestionsContainer = () => {
  const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState(1);
  
  const nextQuestion = () => {
    setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
  };
  
  const previousQuestion = () => {
    setQuestionNumber(questionNumber - 1);
  };

  return(
    switch(questionNumber) {
            case 1:
                return <Question question={no}/>;
            case 2:
                return <Question question={en}/>;
            case 3:
                <Question question={sv}/>;
            case 4:
                return <Question question={da}/>;
            default:
                return <Question question={no}/>;
        })
        <button onClick={nextQuestion}>Next question</button>
        <button onClick={previousQuestion}>Previous question</button>
 }
 
 const Question = ({question}) => {
    return(
        <div>{question}</div>
        )
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```